# 100% CPU with bad execution plan

Tags: performance, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, query-performance

I have a massive problem with 100% CPU spikes because of a bad execution plan used by a specific query. I spend weeks now solve with by my own.

## My Database

My sample DB contains 3 simplified tables.

#### [Datalogger]

```
CREATE TABLE [model].[DataLogger](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] [bigint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DataLogger] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

#### [Inverter]

```
CREATE TABLE [model].[Inverter](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SerialNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Inverter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UK_Inverter] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [DataLoggerID] ASC,
    [SerialNumber] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [model].[Inverter] WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Inverter_DataLogger]
FOREIGN KEY([DataLoggerID])
REFERENCES [model].[DataLogger] ([ID])
```

#### [InverterData]

```
CREATE TABLE [data].[InverterData](
    [InverterID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DayYield] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InverterData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InverterID] ASC,
    [Timestamp] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
```

#### Stats and Maintanance

The `[InverterData]` table contains multiple million rows (differs in multiple instances PaaS) partitioned in monthly junks.

All indexer are defragmentated and all stat rebuild/reorganized as needed on a daily/weekly turn.

## My Query

The query is Entity Framework generated and also simple. But i runes 1,000 times per minute and performance is essential.

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[InverterID] AS [InverterID],
[Extent1].[DayYield] AS [DayYield]
FROM [data].[InverterDayData] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [model].[Inverter] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[InverterID] = [Extent2].[ID]
INNER JOIN [model].[DataLogger] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[DataLoggerID] = [Extent3].[ID]
WHERE ([Extent3].[ProjectID] = @p__linq__0)
AND ([Extent1].[Date] = @p__linq__1) OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

The `MAXDOP 1` hint is for another problem with a slow paralel plan.

## The "good" plan

Over the 90% of time the used plan is lightning fast and looks like this:

[image: fast plan]

## The problem

Over the day the good plan randomly changed to a bad and slow plan.

The "bad" plan is used for 10-60min and then changed back to the "good" plan. The "bad" plan spike the CPU up to permanent 100%.

This is how it looks:

[image: slow plan]

## What I try so far

My first thought was the `Hash Match` is the bad boy. So I modified the query with a new hint.

```
...Extent1].[Date] = @p__linq__1) OPTION (MAXDOP 1, LOOP JOIN)
```

The `LOOP JOIN` should force to use `Nested Loop` instant of `Hash Match`.

The result is that the 90% plan looks like before. But the plan also changed randomly to a bad one.

The "bad" plan now looks like this (table loop order changed):

[image: also slow plan]

The CPU also peeks to 100% during the "new bad" plan.

## Solution?

It comes to my mind to force the "good" plan. But I don't know if this is a good idea.

Inside the plan is an index recommended that included all columns. But this will double the complete table and slow down the inserst which are high frequent.

Please help me!

---

## Update 1 - related to @James comment

Here are both plans (some extra fields shown in the plan because its from the real table):

[Good Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkCVuE37M)

[Bad plan 1 (Hash Match)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkUqxa37f)

[Bad plan 2 (Nested Loop)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S11CPE3mz)

## Update 2 - related to @David Fowler answere

The bad plan is kicking in on random parameter value. So normaly I `@p__linq__1 ='2016-11-26 00:00:00.0000000' @p__linq__0 =20825` the hole day and than the bad plan coming on the same value.

I know the parameter sniffing issue from stored procedures and how to avoid them inside SP. Do you have a hint for me how to avoid this issue for my query?

Creating the recommended index will included all columns. This will double the complete table and slow down the inserst, which are high frequent. That not "feels" right to build an index that simply clone the table. Also I means to double the data size of this big table.

## Update 3 - related to @David Fowler comment

It also didn't work and I think it couldn't. For a better understanding I will explain you how the query is called.

Lets suppose I have 3 entities in the `[DataLogger]` table. Over the day I call the same 3 queries in a roundtrip over and over again:

Base query:
`...WHERE ([Extent3].[ProjectID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Date] = @p__linq__1)`

Parameter:

1. `@p__linq__0 = 1; @p__linq__1 = '2018-01-05 00:00:00.0000000'`
2. `@p__linq__0 = 2; @p__linq__1 = '2018-01-05 00:00:00.0000000'`
3. `@p__linq__0 = 3; @p__linq__1 = '2018-01-05 00:00:00.0000000'`

The parameter `@p__linq__1` is always the same date. But it picks the bad plan on random on a query that runs tousands times with a good plan before. With the same parameter!

## Update 4 - related to @Nic comment

The maintenance runs every night and looks like this.

#### Index

If an Index is fragmentated  more then 5% it is reorganized...

`ALTER INDEX [{index}] ON [{table}] REORGANIZE`

If an Index is fragmentated more then 30% it is rebuilded...

`ALTER INDEX [{index}] ON [{table}] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE=ON, MAXDOP=1)`

If the Index is partitioned it will proofed about fragmentation and altered per partition...

`ALTER INDEX [{index}] ON [{table}] REBUILD PARTITION = {partitionNr} WITH (ONLINE=ON, MAXDOP=1)`

#### Statistics

All stats will be updated if `modification_counter` is higher then 0...

`UPDATE STATISTICS [{schema}].[{object}] ([{stats}]) WITH FULLSCAN`

or on partitioned..

`UPDATE STATISTICS [{schema}].[{object}] ([{stats}]) WITH RESAMPLE ON PARTITIONS({partitionNr})`

The maintenance include all stats, also the auto generated one.

[image: Example]

Comment: You don't mention this, but have you updated stats on any of these tables recently?

Comment: Thx @Nic I added a update on the question. Please see detailed information there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the plans, there are a few differences between the good one and the bad ones.  First thing to notice is that the good plan performs a seek on InverterDayData where as both the bad plans perform a scan.  Why is this, if you check the estimated rows, you'll see that the good plan is expecting 1 row where as the bad plans are expecting 6661 and around 7000 rows.

Now take a look at the compiled parameter values,

**Good Plan**
@p__linq__1 ='2016-11-26 00:00:00.0000000'
@p__linq__0 =20825

**Bad Plans**
@p__linq__1 ='2018-01-03 00:00:00.0000000'
@p__linq__0 = 20686

so it's looking to me like it's a parameter sniffing issue, what parameter values are you passing into that query when it's performing badly?

There is an index recommendation in the bad plans on InverterDayData that looks sensible, I'd try running that in and seeing if it helps you.  It might allow SQL to perform a scan on the table.

Comment: thank for your answer! I have modified the question for you (at the end).

Comment: I didn't realise the suggested index covered the whole table, that's not a good idea.  You could just try an index on the date column.

Comment: using the OPTIMIZE FOR hint will force the plan to compile with the good values, OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR (@p__linq__1 = '2016-11-26 00:00:00.0000000', @p__linq__0 20825) )  but be careful with that one and test it to make sure that it's not going to cause you any unexpected head aches

Comment: hey @david I posted an update.

Comment: Ok it was a parameter sniffing issue! Because of the different row count inside the partitioned table Index SEEK or SCAN is choosen. I fixed it with `...OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` hint.